# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function value() on null [Storefront]

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I have a problem with this theme.

```
2019-05-27T20:26:30+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function value() on null in /public_html/wp-content/themes/storefront/inc/nux/class-storefront-nux-starter-content.php:1162
Stack trace:
#0 /public_html/wp-content/themes/storefront/inc/nux/class-storefront-nux-starter-content.php(1217): Storefront_NUX_Starter_Content->_get_created_starter_content_products()
#1 /public_html/wp-content/themes/storefront/inc/nux/class-storefront-nux-starter-content.php(1007): Storefront_NUX_Starter_Content->_query_starter_content(‘page’, ‘homepage’, true)
#2 /public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): Storefront_NUX_Starter_Content->update_homepage_content(Object(WP_Customize_Manager))
#3 /public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#4 /public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(465): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#5 /public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php(1887): do_action(‘custom en /public_html/wp-content/themes/storefront/inc/nux/class-storefront-nux-starter-content.php en la línea 1162
```

When I try the WordPress Custimizer this happens.

I currently use WooCommerce in its latest version.

I could solve it commenting on the content of the function of line 1162

I do not know what happens, does the same thing happen to someone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, I using a plugin "Advanced Shipment Tracking for WooCommerce" and fixed in update 2.0.1